# wpf programatically set combobox selected item when bound to dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, combobox

I have a combobox which is bound do a dictionary

```
Dictionary<String, myClass> boxItems;
```

The combobox has the following dataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}"></TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

This works fine for loading the values and getting the selected value, however I can't figure out how to set the selected value from codebehind.

any pointers?

I've tried setting selectedItem and selectedValue to a Key (which I know is in the dictionary), but when I load the page, the combobox hasn't selected anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a KeyValuePair with the key you want to select.

You can do something like this:

```
 myCombo.SelectedItem = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("myKey", boxItems["myKey"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your ComboBox

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBoxItem}"/>
```

And use this in a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
private myClass _selectedBoxItem;
public myClass SelectedBoxItem
{
    get { return _selectedBoxItem; }
    set
    {
        _selectedBoxItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedBoxItem");
    }
}
```